# Falling raindrop internal movements

Tags: fluid-dynamics

A falling raindrop has the shape of a drop, because of the friction with the air it's falling through

[image: falling:]

I wonder, does this friction also cause a circular internal movement in the drop like this?

[image]

Or is there no inner movement at all, after the drop shape has formed?

Comment: Keep in mind that, up in the clouds, there are winds blowing this way and that, up and down and sideways, and varying quite rapidly.  It's unlikely that a "steady state" is achieved until the drop is most of it's way to the ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friction is not the only factor that determines the streamline form. Any streamlining would be countered by its surface tension that would keep it nearly spherical. 
Any internal movements would be complicated by oscillations in its form as it interacts with the surrounding air.

A better image for a falling raindrop at terminal velocity from [this NASA article](http://pmm.nasa.gov/node/145) is

[image: http://pmm.nasa.gov/node/145]

Whilst the shape of the drop you suggested seems to need correction, the type of flow seems okay according to [this paper](https://ams.confex.com/ams/pdfpapers/171447.pdf).

> liquid circulation inside of the drop being basically laminar,
>   steady, and axisymmetric.

Comment: I was doubting the cartoonish style of a drop indeed, but I couldn't find a determinative, more realistic image to base this question on. Thanks for answering the question and adding the notes on drop shape.